# Access Child Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-actionbar, searchview

I have a main activity with a dynamic fragment attached to it. The fragment has a listView with an adapter defined in the fragment itself 
Now, I'm trying to implement a SearchView in the actionbar. Everything went smoothly till I reached the onQueryTextChanged method. 
I realized that here, I would have to add a filter to the listView adapter defined in the fragment. 
How do I access this adapter from the main activity?
Since the fragment is dynamic, I can't use findFragmentById() either

Comment: How did you add/attach the fragment?

Comment: Using a FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 0):

This is how its done

```
Fragment fr = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("main frag");
```